# Filter() keywords must be strings

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I am working on a website with Django.

I have created two models, one for photo and the other for a person.

```
class Photo(models.Model):    
    photo  = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'toto')
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length = 250)
    people = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name = _('Person'))

    def display_img(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" /> - %s - %s' % (self.photo, self.description, self.people )

    display_img.allow_tags = True

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length = 50)
```

In my mind what I want is to be able to tag people on a photo.

My problem is that I am able to create a new photo with the **admin**, **but** when I want to modify/view it (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/module/photo/1/) I get this error:

```
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
filter() keywords must be strings
Exception Location: C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py in get_query_set, line 543
```

and I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full traceback would have been useful.

I expect the problem comes from the `related_name` attribute in your `people` field. You've marked this for translation, but that makes no sense: this is an attribute you use in your code, not something for public consumption. Take out the `_()` call.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it solves the problem! You are a genious! 
My understanding of related_name was incorrect. I will go back to documentation.

Next time I will give the traceback ;)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`photo` is object, but you want get this as `str`:

```
return u'<img src="%s" /> - %s - %s' % (self.photo, self.description, self.people )
```

You need `url` attr:

```
return u'<img src="%s" /> - %s - %s' % (self.photo.url, self.description, self.people )
```

My solution about `people`:

```
people = models.ManyToManyField(PersonModel, related_name = _('Persons'), verbose_name=_('Person'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
It does not solve the problem, but it solves an other problem I have about the display of the image. Without it the image was not displayed.

Thank you